# Auto increment a field in mysql after creation of table

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

How to apply a column to be auto-increment after creating the table in mysql? I have googled it, but I got only table level results.

Comment: I have solved this problem. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's applied by altering the table. MYSQL command is:
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY col_name INT AUTO_INCREMENT;